# Package apache2-mpm-itk in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, ubuntu-15.10

I'd love to use `apache2-mpm-itk` module as mode for Apache2 servers. I used it without trouble on 14.10.

However, upgrading to 15.10 i see that package is [not available](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/apache2-mpm-itk) anymore, so i cannot find a way to install it with `APT`.

How do i install this module without compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [15.10 universe repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libapache2-mpm-itk).

Comment: [libapache2-mpm-itk 2.4.7-02-1.1 (amd64 binary) in ubuntu wily](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libapache2-mpm-itk/2.4.7-02-1.1) and [mpm-itk package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpm-itk)